# How to render ViewBag.Message when it is not null but without a temporary variable?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I can render `ViewBag.Message` in a Razor view as follows.

```
<h1>Message: @{string message = ViewBag.Message?? "Empty";} @message</h1>
```

Is there any shorter way to do so without using a temporary variable `message`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an explicit expression with parenthesis:

```
<h1>Message: @(ViewBag.Message ?? "Empty")</h1>
```